# kernel panic-not syncing Error after driver installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, kernel, mount

First off, just to clarify I have google searched this and most of the people are advanced users and know how to use the terminal, while I cannot operate it very well. Also most of them I don't think is coorelated with my problem even though the error is the same.

Anyway, so basically I installed Ubuntu 16.04 amd64 from the USB, no errors were found and I was going fairly well seeing as I failed to install 2 versions of Ubuntu in the same day. and then I clicked on Software Center and there were 21 updates. I clicked on the top blue install button to install them all, and I think they were at the middle when I saw all of them once again available to press and nothing was progressing. so I pressed the blue on again and still nothing. I pressed each of them seperately and nothing happened. I clicked on settings and the setting icons were disappeared, and most of the settings functionalities were gone. I restarted the computer and was greeted by this error. Any help? Thanks!

Additional maybe useful info: 
I had put 10 gigabytes of space for the OS and 8 gigabytes for swap. If there is anything related to low disk space and it bugging out, let me know. thanks in advance!

Comment: Related to disk size: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

It seems that your main partition _might_ be too small. (Minimum is 8 GB, recommended minimum is at least 15 GB. I would advise to make it something like 25 GB, so you'll have some space for downloads etc..

Comment: Thanks! I posted a question thinking it would be related to disk size. Mind checking out or can I post it here asweell?

Comment: I checked it, they pretty much said the same as I did :) can you get any Ubuntu terminal running (e.g. from the live USB) and execute `lsblk`? Then post the results (to the new question). We could recommend disk layouts to you then :)

Comment: Accidentally posted it here. Posting it as a question! :C

Comment: Editing one of your existing questions would have been fine, since it was directly related :) But I messed up, wrong command, I meant `df -h` or `parted`... But it's alright, the point came across, less Swap, more Root partition space.